# ssmtp: Authorization failed for corporate mailserver

Tags: command-line, email, ssmtp

Our corporate has its own mailserver and I want to send mail to it from command line. I've install smtp and configure it.

Configuration in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

```
root=username@symantric.com
mailhub=mailserver.symantric.com:25
rewriteDomain=symantric.com
hostname=gtmpc
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=username
AuthPass=password
UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
```

Configuration in /etc/ssmtp/revaliases

```
root:username@symantric.com:mailserver.symantric.com:25
mainuser:username@symantric.com:mailserver.symantric.com:25
```

When i run command:

```
echo "Test message from Linux server using ssmtp" | sudo ssmtp -vvv username@symantric.com
```

Output:

```
[<-] 220 mailserver.symantric.com ESMTP Postfix
[->] EHLO gtmpc
[<-] 250 DSN
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
[->] EHLO gtmpc
[<-] 250 DSN
[->] AUTH LOGIN
[<-] 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[->] Z2F5YXRyaS5wYXRlbA==
[<-] 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[<-] 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
ssmtp: Authorization failed (535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure)
```

Output of /var/log/syslog:

```
Dec 21 10:41:12 gtmpc sSMTP[23619]: Creating SSL connection to host
Dec 21 10:41:12 gtmpc sSMTP[23619]: SSL connection using RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
Dec 21 10:41:12 gtmpc sSMTP[23619]: Authorization failed (535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure)
```

Comment: No server listening to port 25 on host `smtp.mailserver.com`? Firewall at that host?

Comment: When I did `telnet host 25`, it can connect.

Comment: @waltinator but `telnet localhost 25` gives me error: `Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you solve your problem ?